# Read permission state (enable/disable) for an app in android

Tags: android, android-permissions, permission-denied

Assume my app contains following permission camera, Write internal storage etc... while installing user accepting all permission & through app manager they can disable and enable particular permission for a particular App. so what i need is how to get the **permission status** **pro grammatically** in android. Can any one please help me regarding.

Comment: anyone please comment about it...

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkSelfPermission (String permission)` to see if the user has a particular permission; also check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)). Also give a read of [Androids page on permissions](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) it includes the new best practices for Marshmallow.

*Edit:* Here is a second way:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
int hasPerm = pm.checkPermission(
    android.Manifest.permission.PERMISSION_TO_CHECKS_NAME, 
    context.getPackageName());
if (hasPerm != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   // run code
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur quick response but i cant use checkSelfPermission.

Comment: i used this code, even though i switched to camera in denied state it given output as permission granted only...